# Paypal payout get sender item id

Tags: php, paypal

How do I get the "sender item id" from a retrived PayoutItem

```
try {

            $output = \PayPal\Api\PayoutItem::get($payoutItemId, $this->apiContext);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return $e->getMessage();
        }

// trasaction_id - works fine
            $transactionStatus = $output->getTransactionId();

            // trasaction_status - works fine
            $transactionId = $output->getTransactionStatus();

// ERROR
$senderItemId = $output->getSenderItemId();
```

Error:

```
Call to undefined method PayPal\Api\PayoutItemDetails::getSenderItemId()
```

upon inspection it looks like the PayoutItem class has the `getSenderItemId()` public function available - but the PayoutItemDetails class which is returned by the static `get` method on PayoutItem does not.

How can I get the senderItemId? :(

Payout item class - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/PayoutItem.php

Answer (score 0):

So turns out PayoutItemDetails class also returns a PayoutItem object.

So I can get the sender item id like so:

```
// WRONG
$senderItemId = $output->getSenderItemId();

// RIGHT
$senderItemId = $output->getPayoutItem()->getSenderItemId();
```

Comment: The senderBatchId may also be useful:

$senderBatchID = $output->getBatchHeader()->getSenderBatchHeader()->getSenderBatchId();